# Explain the difference in "First time only" Shehechiyanu

Tags: yom-tov, shehecheyanu

When Shehechiyanu is said "publicly" (i.e., on holidays, Kiddush or prior to certain mitzvoth - occasions when everyone must say it vs. say when wearing new clothes.) it is generally done just once on the occasion of the first time performing the mitzvah.

However, I am a bit puzzled regarding understanding this rule of "first time only" esp. when it concerns Yom Tov Sheini in Galut.

There seems to be an inconsistency, regarding things done during Succot as well as Rosh Hashanna.

On Rosh Hashanna, the mitzvah to blow the shofar is one day. By that logic, we should be saying Shehechiyanu only on the 1st time we blow the shofar. Yet, we say Shehechiyanu on the 2nd day, also. I understand that the reason we do it on the 2nd day is due to *sfeika deyoma* (we're not sure which day is the 1st day.)

In contrast, the mitzvah for taking Lulav (from the Torah's statement) is on the first day, only. Outside of Israel, we say Shehechiyanu on the 1st day, only, not on the 2nd day. Why isn't this following the same rules as for shofar? If we're not sure which day was the first day, why shouldn't we say Shehechiyanu on lulav on the 2nd day?

Comment: Isn't Rosh Hashanah because yom arichta and not sefeika deyoma?

Comment: @robev That is an element. I left that out, intentionally, as my thinking is that if, in fact, it is considered *Yoma Arichta*, that would suggest that we SHOULDN'T say it twice, because, it is just one day altogether.

Comment: You're right. See Simman 600 MB SK 7 (ז) וי"א לאומרו וכו' - היינו אפילו בלא בגד חדש ופרי חדש משום דהא היום אין יוצאין בתקיעה של אתמול ולא אמרינן יומא אריכתא הוא וה"ה נמי בברכת התקיעה ומ"מ לכתחילה טוב שילבש התוקע בגד חדש בשופר [מ"א וש"א]

Comment: @robev I'm glad that I got you thinking. However, I think this may have something to do with distinguishing Shofar from Lulav, though, I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @Daniel As perhaps implicit in the answer there, the distinction from shofar is more subtle than from the day itself.  So not necessarily a duplicate.

Comment: The MB cited by Alex in the related question seems to address the distinction from shofar, though I can't say I understand what he's saying.  I would have suggested that it has something to do with the fact that one typically puts together the 4 minim on/before yom tov and that act itself merits a shehecheyanu; as opposed to shofar which isn't typically fashioned by the baal tokeah - suggesting perhaps that if the baal tokeah did fashion his own shofar, maybe he wouldn't make a shehecheyanu on the second day of rosh hashana.